# How to reduce HTML output on Drupal forms

Tags: 7, forms, theming

How to let Drupal **print only necessary HTML in *forms***. I want to override fields input.

This is the current code for `node add form`:

```
<form ...>
...
    <div class="field-type-text field-name-field-price-ad field-widget-text-textfield form-wrapper" id="edit-field-price-ad">             
      <div id="field-price-ad-add-more-wrapper">                 
        <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-price-ad-und-0-value">                        
          <label for="edit-field-price-ad-und-0-value">Price</label>                       
          <input class="text-full form-text required" type="text" id="edit-field-price-ad-und-0-value" name="field_price_ad[und][0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="55" />                     
          <div class="description">Text</div>                 
        </div>             
      </div>         
    </div>    
    <div class="field-type-youtube field-name-field-video-ad field-widget-youtube form-wrapper" id="edit-field-video-ad">      
      <div id="field-video-ad-add-more-wrapper">        
        <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-video-ad-und-0-input">             
          <label for="edit-field-video-ad-und-0-input">Video</label>            
          <input type="text" id="edit-field-video-ad-und-0-input" name="field_video_ad[und][0][input]" value="" size="60" maxlength="1024" class="form-text" />          
          <div class="description">Text</div>        
        </div>      
      </div>    
    </div>
...
</form>
```

I want something like this:

```
<form ...>
...
    <div id="edit-field-price-ad">                                    
          <label for="edit-field-price-ad-und-0-value">Price</label>                       
          <input class="text-full form-text required" type="text" id="edit-field-price-ad-und-0-value" name="field_price_ad[und][0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="55" />                     
          <div class="description">Text</div>        
    </div>    
    <div id="edit-field-video-ad">         
          <label for="edit-field-video-ad-und-0-input">Video</label>            
          <input type="text" id="edit-field-video-ad-und-0-input" name="field_video_ad[und][0][input]" value="" size="60" maxlength="1024" class="form-text" />          
          <div class="description">Text</div>          
    </div>
...
</form>
```

Using [`theme_form_element`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7) I was able to remove third div (form-item). I cannot figure out how to edit first 2 div wraps.

Answer (score 1):

With [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) and sub module Display Suite Extras you can remove unnecessary wrappers.

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer `theme_hook` or `my_custom_module_hook` solution, no more modules. This will be just some small snipped I cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences) module - you can override any templates with your own.

Comment: You are 3th person which suggest me something for override fields output. It means I'm asking wrong :-) I want to override fields input (Drupal forms).

Comment: You're not asking wrong @Jasom, its our fault for not reading it properly, you've been perfectly clear in the question. what we're expecting the question to be is a fairly often-asked one, and it's just so similar to what you need. I'll take a proper look in a bit, but what you're asking is a big pain to change IIRC. The function responsible is called field_default_form or field_form_default, can't remember which off the top of my head

Comment: I see. Check out [Theming Node Forms](https://www.drupal.org/node/1092122) and [How to Override Forms](http://www.wdtutorials.com/how-to-override-forms-using-custom-template-drupal-tutorial/7#.VgPCoY-qpBc). But you will probably need to do something similar for each of the fields individually.

Comment: Yea, as suspected this is probably going to be a pain. I think your best approach will be to use `hook_field_widget_form_alter()`, and change the wrapping element type from `container` to `item`. That might stop the div coming out, assuming `item` types don't also have a wrapping div. If that doesn't work, you're probably going to need to do some more serious surgery on the render arrays. Keep in mind that there's at least a small possibility some of those field types will rely on the container existing for javascript/form submission reasons

Comment: You can see what render arrays are responsible for the markup you're seeing here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.form.inc/function/field_default_form/7

Comment: If you want really architecturally clean solution, without hacking around Field API (because IMO the solution will be fragile and will keep breaking up), you could generate your own form (e.g. using Backbone), where you can control the markup fully, and submit it to a REST service, which will populate fields (see [example](http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/drupal-7-backbone-js-part-1-setting-upinstallation/)).